# REST api & sourceId

Tags: rest-api, source

There are many REST endpoints that require passing a sourceId parameter.

Where do I get the value for sourceId?

https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.5-admin/tag/inventorysources#operation/GetV1InventorySources

GET https://mymagentodomain.com/rest/V1/inventory/sources
returns

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "source_code": "default",
            "name": "Default Source",
            "enabled": true,
            "description": "Default Source",
            "latitude": 0,
            "longitude": 0,
            "country_id": "US",
            "postcode": "00000",
            "use_default_carrier_config": true,
            "carrier_links": [],
            "extension_attributes": {
                "is_pickup_location_active": false,
                "frontend_name": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": []
    },
    "total_count": 1
}
```

Where's the sourceId ?

Answer (score 0):

`sourceId` or `source_code` is the code defined for Inventory Sources for magento weshop.

You can find all Sources at Stores >> Inventory >> Sources

[image]

At the moment your website having default source so it is returning single source.

you can you `source_code` to Get Source data by given code.

`http://magento2.local/magento241/rest/all/V1/inventory/sources/default`

Comment: thank you for the quick response.    Is there no way to obtain the sourceIds progmatically?   Magento V1 had this Rest endpoint: /api/rest/multiwhse/id/productId1,productId2      which would return stock level in each warehouse.   how can this be accomplished in V2